# What are the necessary and sufficient condition for $f(x)$ to be expandable into Legendre polynomials?

Tags: mathematical-physics, legendre-polynomials

In physics, we often expand functions $f(x)$ of a real variable $x$ which is piecewise continuous in the interval $(-1,1)$ along with its derivatives, in terms of Legendre polynomials $\{P_n(x)\}$ as $$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}c_nP_n(x)$$ where $c_n$ can be obtained using $$c_n=\frac{2n+1}{2}\int\limits_{-1}^{+1}f(x)P_n(x)dx.$$

*Is it always possible to do such an expansion for any $f(x)$? I'm looking for the necessary and sufficient conditions.*

Comment: The French Wikipedia article on [Legendre’s polynomial](https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynôme_de_Legendre) provides elements on Legendre expansion of functions. It provides more elements on that topic than the English version.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that the series converges in the $L^2$ sense (common in physics), then it follows from [orthogonality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials#Orthogonality) and completeness. [This Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1598540/252672) derives the completeness of the polynomials from the completeness of the trigonometric functions. Proof of the latter requires some functional analysis. [This Answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/128874/252672) outlines a proof ("glossing over technical details").

Comment: Yes, every $L^2(-1,1)$ function can be expanded in terms of Legendre polynomials.